# How to setup the launch.json for debugging react backend project inside VS code?

Tags: reactjs, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am learning [React.js](https://reactjs.org/) and would like to enable debugging in VS Code. I tried many different scripts but they never stop at the breakpoints. I want to stop at breakpoints in the VS Code, not in the browser. Could someone show the correct script for it? Simply, I want to run debugging as in ASP.net in visual studio IDE.

break point example :
[image]

Comment: I don't have the answer for you unfortunately, but I make a very strong recommendation that you learn to use the debugger built into the browser. It's an extremely powerful tool the better you know it the less you will need your editor for debugging

Comment: Thank you for your fed back. For the frontend, it is ideal but for the backend, I need a VScode debugger.